# Multiple conditions in an IF statement in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Probably an easy one but my prog skills are limited.  I've created an account entry tool and want to warn the user if they've entered a credit amount for an Expenditure type of which there are two types; "Restricted_Expenditure" and "Unrestricted Expenditure". Typically values of this type should be debits.

I can get it to work for one type in the statement, but not if I add the other expenditure type in an "or" statement.

Any help appreciated - is there an "Or If..." type function I could use?

My code is

```
If inputWks.Range("d9") > 0 And inputWks.Range("d11") = "Restricted_Expenditure" Or "Unrestricted_Expenditure" Then

Dim Response As Integer

 Response = MsgBox(prompt:="You've entered a credit amount against an expenditure type.  If this is correct then press 'Yes' or else press 'No' to change", Buttons:=vbYesNo)

If Response = vbYes Then

GoTo Line1

Else

Exit Sub

End If
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`ElseIf`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php)?

Comment: Is that all your code? Because if it is, you're missing an End If statement, but it might come, if it's not all the code :)

Answer (score 10):

In VBA we can not use `if jj = 5 or 6 then` we must use `if jj = 5 or jj = 6 then`

maybe this:

```
If inputWks.Range("d9") > 0 And (inputWks.Range("d11") = "Restricted_Expenditure" Or inputWks.Range("d11") = "Unrestricted_Expenditure") Then
```